# How to get the number of users who have groups in a certain period of time

Tags: php, laravel

There is a category of users $ participants who are in groups and no, groups have a start time $ start_time and end $ end_time, I need to deduce count of those users who are in groups on a specific dateRange, I do not know how to write the last condition and how to link dateRange to users because they belong to the groups parameters.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Group;
use app\Participants;
use Carbon\Carbon;


 class ParticipantCounts extends Controller
 {
  public function ParticipantCountsWithGroups()
 {
   $participants = $Participants::has('groups')->get();


    $dateRange = "DD.MM.YY-DD.MM.YY";
    $splitTimeStamp = explode("-", $dateRange);
    $start_time = $splitTimeStamp[0];
    $end_time = $splitTimeStamp[1];

    Carbon::parse($start_time)->format('Y-m-d');
    Carbon::parse($end_time)->format('Y-m-d');

    $participants->where(function($query)
    {
      $query->where('start_date')->whereBetween('end_date');
    })->orWhere(function($query))
        {
            $query->where('end_time')->whereBetween('end_time');
        }
    }
}
```

[image: There is a simple table]

Answer (score 0):

Below should give you group_id and particular count in that group for date range.

```
Participants::join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'participants.group_id')
    ->select('participants.group_id', \DB::raw('count(*) as participant_count'))
    ->where('groups.start_time', '>=', $startDate)
    ->where('groups.end_time', '<=', $endDate)
    ->groupBy('participants.group_id')
    ->get();
```